# What is the problem I am having with using arrays with classes?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, external

I have been working on a project for my computer science class and have encountered an issue with the code working. I am shown no error except when I try to compile and I get an error that reads:

Exception thrown: write access violation.
_Left was 0xCCCCCCCC.

The purpose of my project is to take a list of names from an external file, read them into an array, sort said array and then output the sorted list all while using a class for the code.
Here is a copy of my code and I would like to extend my gratitude to whoever can help me through my issue:

````
**Header File**

#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


class person
{
public:
    person();
    bool get(ifstream&);
    void put(ofstream&);

private:
    int capacity = 0;
    string first_name[CAPACITY];
    string last_name[CAPACITY];
    int age[CAPACITY];



};```

**Header function definitions cpp file**

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>

const int CAPACITY=20;
using namespace std;

#include "Person.h"

//Names constructor
//Postcondition both first name and last name initialized to zero


person::person()
{
    first_name[CAPACITY] = "";
    last_name[CAPACITY] = "";
    age[CAPACITY]=0;

}

bool person::get(ifstream& in)
{
    in >> first_name[CAPACITY] >> last_name[CAPACITY] >> age[CAPACITY];
    return(in.good());

}
void person::put(ofstream &out)
{
    out << first_name[CAPACITY] << last_name[CAPACITY] << age[CAPACITY];
}

**cpp file which holds main**

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

const int CAPACITY = 20;
using namespace std;
#include "Person.h"


void pop(string *xp, string *yp);
void sort(string name[CAPACITY], int count);

int main()
{
    class person names[CAPACITY];
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    string filename;
    string name[CAPACITY];
    int n = 0;

    cout << "Enter the file name you wish to open" << endl;
    cin >> filename;
    infile.open(filename + ".txt");
    outfile.open("Person_New.txt");

    if (infile.fail())
    {
        cout << "The file requested did not open" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        names[n].get(infile);
        n++;
    }
    sort(name, CAPACITY);
    for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
    {
        names[i].put(outfile);
    }
    cout << "The file has been created" << endl;

    infile.close();





}
void pop(string *xp, string *yp)
{
    string temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
void sort(string name[CAPACITY], int count)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
    {

        for (j = 0; j < count - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (name[j] > name[j + 1])
            {
                pop(&name[j], &name[j + 1]);
            }

        }
    }
} 

Once again Thank you for any support
````

Comment: You don't need *any* array in `person` class. And you are using them incorrectly - `[CAPACITY]` means something different when *declaring* an array and when you are *using* an array. `name` array in `main` is never initialized with anything useful - all you have there are empty strings. Note that it's completely unrelated to your `names` array. Also [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: I don't think that's how you are supposed to use strings actually

Comment: I'd suggest ditching the resource you are currently using for learning C++ and getting [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead. C++ is not an easy language and using it correctly is even harder.

Comment: Amongst many other things, statements like ` first_name[CAPACITY] = "";` write past the end of the array. Valid array indices are `0...CAPACITY-1` in your case.

Comment: Don't use arrays, use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the compiler is getting upset that you are trying to write (i.e. assign a value) at an address that you do not have permission to access. I believe your constructor for the class `person` might be at fault because of how this class stores its variables, as well as the class header:

*Constructor for the class person:*

```
`person::person(){
    first_name[CAPACITY] = "";
    last_name[CAPACITY] = "";
    age[CAPACITY] = 0;
}`
```

*Class header for the class person:*

```
`class person{
    public:
        //stuff
    private:
        int capacity = 0;
        std::string first_name[CAPACITY];
        std::string last_name[CAPACITY];
        int age[CAPACITY];
        //more stuff
}`
```

C++ is very specific about its naming conventions, so it makes a distinction between `capacity` and `CAPACITY`. Because of this, the variable `CAPACITY` is not defined within the Person.h file.

Also, because `CAPACITY` is set to a fixed value in your Person.cpp file, whenever you use `first_name[CAPACITY]`, `last_name[CAPACITY]`, or `age[CAPACITY]` to assign new values, you are only updating the values at the index equal to `CAPACITY` unless you update the value of `CAPACITY` itself. In the code you provided, `CAPACITY` is equal to 20, so your program attempts to update exclusively index 20 with each method call. This will likely cause issues since the `person` class only attempts to make its arrays on the runtime stack, with a size of 0 each.

Separately, it seems like you want an array of people, but it appears that you are attempting to use a single person object to store the names and ages of multiple people by making these all arrays. Instead, I would recommend making `first_name`, `last_name`, and `age` *not* arrays, but rather single variables. Then, you can manipulate an array of type `person` using your `CAPACITY` variable. You got pretty close, but you can instead declare it as `person myPersonArray[CAPACITY]` (no need to mention "class" in front of it -- just be sure that you have `#include "Person.h"` in your main.cpp file). When you want to update a specific person, you can perform an operation like `myPersonArray[updateThisIndexNum].update(newFirstName, newLastName, newAge)` or some logical equivalent.

As a final note, I almost always highly recommend against using `!infile.eof()` to control your while loop when reading any file because `eof()` *only indicates whether you have tried to read past the end of an input file*. I would highly recommend checking out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) on Stack Overflow where people far more knowledgeable than I explain exactly why this is usually dangerous and how to avoid it.